# VideoView android, prevent ontouch for 5 seconds. Android

Tags: android, video, onclicklistener, android-videoview

I have a video view which plays different video clips upon different events of the user. I have set up the videoview that when the user taps the view, it stops the video and returns to the previous screen. However I want to set it that the video cannot be tapped for 5 seconds (for example), and only after 5 seconds if the screen is tapped the video will stop. [Thus the movie will play for a minimum of 5 seconds, before the ability to stop it]

Here is the code for the videoview on ontouch listener:

```
  videoView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {


                    Log.d(TAG, "video clicked");

                    videoView.stopPlayback();

                    videoView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);


                    return true;
                }
            });
```

I tried using handler but I couldnt figure out where to put it. Since if I put the stopPlayback method in the handler after 5 seconds, then if someone clicks on the view before 5 seconds the video stops after five seconds. ,But what I want is that nothing at all happens with a tap before 5 seconds.

Thanks so much,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not set the onTouchListener until after the 5 second delay. That way, for the first 5 seconds, no touch events are being registered, where as after 5 seconds when you setOnTouchListener the listener is ready for a touch event. Try something like this:

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {

        //Execute code here

        videoView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

                    Log.d(TAG, "video clicked");

                    videoView.stopPlayback();

                    videoView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                    return true;
                }
            }); 

    }
}, 5000);
```

or, using Ajinkya S's suggestion:

```
videoView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

            Log.d(TAG, "video clicked");

            videoView.stopPlayback();

            videoView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            return true;
        }
    });
videoView.setEnabled(false);


Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {

        //Execute code here
        videoView.setEnabled(true);

    }
}, 5000);
```

Comment: How do i detect when the video has started?

Comment: I don't know - do you not have an event triggering the video start?

Comment: Try making the video view setenabled(false) in handler and after finishing make it true. Or else disable it's clickable event

Comment: The thing is that, I start the videos lots of times from different button and places in the app. I don't think its a good idea to create a new onClickListener every time a video is played.

Comment: I added a second example based on Ajinkya's suggestion which simply sets whether the view is enabled or not.